# My $stmt Insert executes twice, mysqli with same data only once

Tags: php, function, mysqli

I have these two functions. The $stmt query inserts the data twice in my dbase, even with the checking routine.

Been trying to catch the error all day, but i just cannot find it.

The regular MySQLi routine called the exact same way, does indeed insert the data just once.

I just cannot wrap my head around why. Did some echo checks, echo'ed SQL inserts etcetera. I just don't know what is happening. I've not used the $stmt a lot yet, but wanted to better my programmer's life somewhat. This doesn't help :-)

Running the tests on XAMPP with:
Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0g PHP/7.2.1
Clientversie van database: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407
PHP-versie: 7.2.1

This code inserts it twice:

```
$result = mysql_insert_array_serialised($conn, $dbt_serialsets, $_POST, $addon);


function mysql_insert_array_serialised($conn, $table, $data, $addon = "mc_api") {

        $random_code = substr(str_shuffle(MD5(microtime())), 0, 12);
        $settings    = serialize($data);
        $uid         = $_SESSION['uid'];

        $sql_chk = "SELECT sn FROM $table WHERE sn = ?";

        if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql_chk)) {
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $random_code);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();

            if ($stmt->num_rows == 0) {
                // SN doesnt already exist
                $sql_insert = 'INSERT INTO ' . $table . ' (uid, addon, sn, settings) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)';
                if ($stmt       = $conn->prepare($sql_insert)) {
                    $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $uid, $addon, $random_code, $settings);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
                        echo $stmt->error;
                    }else{
                        return array(
                        "mysqli_error"         => false,
                        "sn"                   => $random_code
                        );  
                    }

                } else {
                    echo 'Could not prepare statement!';
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Whereas this one, with the exact same data, does the job as supposed to. One insert.

```
$result = mysql_insert_array($conn, $dbt_serialsets, $_POST, $addon);

function mysql_insert_array($conn, $table, $data, $addon) {

    $random_code = substr(str_shuffle(MD5(microtime())), 0, 12);
    $settings    = serialize($data);
    $uid         = $_SESSION['uid'];

    if ($conn->query("INSERT INTO $table (uid, addon, sn, settings) VALUES ('" . $uid . "', '" . $addon . "' , '" . $random_code . "', '" . $settings . "')")) {
        return array(
            "mysqli_error"         => false,
            "mysqli_insert_id"     => $conn->insert_id,
            "mysqli_affected_rows" => $conn->affected_rows,
            "mysqli_info"          => $conn->info,
            "sn"                   => $random_code
        );

    } else {
        return array("mysqli_error" => $conn->error);
    }
}
```

I'm puzzled. Few replies on similar issues, one said it was solved once uploaded to the http server, I'm only running this on my local test XAMPP

Since a few of you thought the double $stmt->execute was the issue, it isn't. One is for the select (check for exisitng), one was for insert new data.

The original function was like this, changed that back and still inserts twice:

```
function mysql_insert_array_serialised_test($conn, $table, $data, $addon = "mc_api") {

    $random_code = substr(str_shuffle(MD5(microtime())), 0, 12);
    $settings    = serialize($data);
    $uid         = $_SESSION['uid'];

    $sql_insert = 'INSERT INTO ' . $table . ' (uid, addon, sn, settings) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)';
    if ($stmt       = $conn->prepare($sql_insert)) {
        $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $uid, $addon, $random_code, $settings);
        $stmt->execute();
        if (!$stmt->execute()) {
            echo $stmt->error;
        } else {
            return array(
                "mysqli_error" => false,
                "sn"           => $random_code
            );
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Could not prepare statement!';
    }        
}
```

Apparently, I did not read well. My apologies. The double executes referred to in the post are there, and removing 1 did indeed help. I thought one was for checking if there was a valid result, not actually executing the query again.

- goes to the shame corner *

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two calls to `$stmt->execute()` both of which will perform the `INSERT`:

```
                $stmt->execute();
                if (!$stmt->execute()) {
```

You can just remove the first one.

Comment: That code is there for the check for duplicates. I added that to see if that mattered. It didn't. That leaves me with another question though: don't I need the execute to get the SELECT result as well in this case? Either way, I'll remove it and try again.

Comment: @KimK.the call to `execute` that is duplicated is after your prepare of the `INSERT` statement (`$stmt       = $conn->prepare($sql_insert)`); it's not related to the check for duplicates above.

Comment: Just noticed what you actually meant and updated post/accepted your answer. Thought that second one was there for error checking only. Kind of like with num_rows and that kind of routines. Thanks for the lesson.

Answer (score 3):

It executes twice because the code tells it to:

```
                $stmt->execute();
                if (!$stmt->execute()) {
                    echo $stmt->error;
                }else{
                    // ....
                }
```

To fix this, remove the first `$stmt->execute()` line (in this block, not the one for the previous query) or assign the result to a variable and check that.